# Routing algorithm for Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I don't know the exact meaning of the question but someone asked me this question in interview. I just want to know that there's something like that, we use any route algorithm in Wordpress?

Comment: you can check this topic on wordpress stack exchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/141072/how-does-routing-on-wordpress-work/141087#141087?newreg=eafbfdb70a6946d7a300d6d47b2365e9

Comment: Thanks for replied. I know that how to work route in wordpress but i want to know routing algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a trick question because routing would mean mapping an HTTP request to trigger specific function or method that would handle the request which is not something that WordPress does (there is a section about WordPress at the bottom). In simple word, you read the HTTP request information to decide what function is going to be triggered.

**Bit more details in simple words**

if you are building a PHP project from scratch and want to display specific content or trigger a method/function there are usually two option (without routing)

- Using POST , GET or REQUEST variables and complex conditional statements to achieve what you want, so a result URL could be something like this

  http://example.com/index.php?view=pubications&per_page=5
- Setting a PHP file for each type of content

  http://example.com/publications.php?per_page=5

However, if you created a Router (Routing algorithm as you named it or routing system) then pushed all requests to index.php and have the latter include let's say something like this:

```
// Include the Router class
require('classes/router.php');
// Include functions responsible for display our content
require('view/display.php');
```

I'll not go into how to build a router, just giving examples assuming that you already have one just to give you an idea how routing works.

So assuming you have a router and function to display a contact form for example, you'd also include something like this:

```
Router::add('/contact-us', get_contact_form(),'get');
Router::add('/contact-us', handle_contact_form(),'post');
```

Then initialize the Router

```
Router::initialize('/');
```

Again assuming you have a complete Router, the above function would tell the index.php file to handle HTTP requests on this URL differently:
http://example.com/contact-us

If it's the default request type GET, trigger this function `get_contact_form()`, but if the request type is POST trigger this one `handle_contact_form()` which will act and display content differently depending on your needs.

That's great because it would be instead of something like

```
http://example.com/index.php?page=contact-us
```

index.php content would handle the request differently since there is no router.

```
// Include functions responsible for display our content
require('view/display.php');

if( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'contact-us'){
    echo get_contact_form();
}

if( isset($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'contact-us' && isset($_POST['contact_submit']) ){
    echo handle_contact_form();
}
```

Imagine how long and ugly this would look like if you have a lot of pages and a complex site.

**So back to WordPress**

If you have a new installation you'd notice that the URLs looks something like this:

```
http://example.com/?p=62
http://example.com/?cat=1
http://example.com/?author=3
```

So it would just take URL parameters then build a WP_Query based on that, if is `p` then look for posts in database by ID, if `cat` then look for categories by ID and so on... (that's the simple explanation, there is a lot going on of course in the back-end, but just to give an idea).

You might notice after changing permalink structure that the above examples would now look something like this:

```
http://example.com/post-slug
http://example.com/author/name
http://example.com/category/uncategorized
```

This might look like routing, but it isn't, let's go in a bit more details about how this works.

When requesting a (pretty-link) URL on WordPress, first thing that happens is that the `.htaccess` looks for a folder/file with same name on the server, if it exists it will served, if not, it would send that request to the index.php file which does one thing:

```
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

loading the `wp-blog-header.php` file, which will make a small check to make sure the code only run once then the following:

```
// Load the WordPress library.
require_once( dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-load.php' );

// Set up the WordPress query.
wp();

// Load the theme template.
require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/template-loader.php' );
```

Let's not go deeper into these files, what's concerns us the most is what 'wp-load.php' and  'template-loader.php' does

**wp-load.php**

This one among other things, looks for wp-config, make sure everything is set correctly, then connect to the database, of course after a lot of initialization, setting up constants loading a lot files that handles different parts of WordPress structure. Part of this process is that WordPress tries to match the request URL with a large set of rule called **rewrite rules** which are set of **regular expressions**, when a match is found WordPress will translate that URL into a database query using `[WP_Query][1]` class which is located at `wp-includes/class-wp-query.php` and this class will save the query results among other things (query type...etc)

**template-loader.php**

This one handles the display part, it uses some WordPress function that make use of WP_Query (eg:is_home()) to find out what type of content is to be displayed, then loads the the correct template based on that, and finally the template will use WP_Query to show the result.

Comment: Thanks for replied. I know about all things above, which you mentioned about routing and very helpful answered but how you explain in few lines if someone ask routing algorithm in interview ?

Comment: You can summarize what you know, you could say that WordPress uses a set of regular expressions called rewrite rules and translate that into a query, meaning it compare things and figure out what the URL represents and use this information to query posts/pages from database and then display the content simply.